# T-Sql Multiple DateDiff with Multiple Start and End Dates Stored in the Same Table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on an ERP system that has several workflows for different business processes.  In this system I have access to views the vendor provides, not all the underlying tables.  There is a log table that records and time stamps every time a record enters and completes one of the workflow steps.

What I want to do is write a query that displays the time in days, to one decimal, how long each record spent in each one of the steps.

In the view I have access to there is no primary key - it looks like this:

```
Record_id  Workflow_id  Workflow_Step_id Start_Date            Result_Key Complete_Date
 Record 1    1422                1        20-Feb-07 9:16:35 PM   7320       23-Mar-07 2:16:10 PM
 Record 1    1422                2        23-Mar-07 2:16:10 PM   7320       23-Mar-08 3:13:30 PM
 Record 1    1422                3        23-Mar-08 3:13:30 PM   7320       23-Mar-10 8:18:10 AM
 Record 1    1422                4        23-Mar-10 8:18:10 AM   7320       23-Mar-13 4:06:57 PM
```

Essentially the Record_id is what record the time stamp is recording, there are thousands of these and they are not unique because each time a record passes a step in the workflow it gets a new record stamped again.

Workflow_id is simply what workflow the record is going through (i.e. Purchase Order, Engineering Change Request, etc.) - there are multiple workflows so I would need to filter on which workflow is being used for the final results

Workflow_Step_id let's me know what step in the workflow process this times stamp is reflecting.

Result_Key is a numeric way of saying "Passed" or "Rejected" - in this case '7320' means 'Passed' and that's what I'm most interested in (if it matters).

Start_Date and Complete_Date are obvious, but that's what I'm trying to measure the time between, for each step in the Workflow_Step_Id for each record as it goes through the entire workflow.

Ideally this is what my end results would look like, filtered on the proper Workflow_id (1422):

```
 Record_id  Step_1  Step_2  Step_3  Step_4 
  Record 1    30.0    1.0     10.4     3.2
  Record 2    10.1    8.2      7.3     4.8
  Record 3     2.1    4.1      8.4     6.1
```

(The math is not exact to the data I provided above, this is just to illustrate what I want the final results to look like.)

Comment: It popped up automatically - If someone can show me how to do it in MySql I could probably figure out how to make it work

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT Record_ID, Workflow_Step_ID,CAST(DATEDIFF(hour,Start_Date,Complete_Date)*1.0/24 AS DECIMAL(19,1)) AS Day_Diff
              FROM Table1
              )
SELECT *
FROM cte
PIVOT(MAX(Day_DIFF) FOR WorkFlow_Step_ID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4]))pvt
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/506b4/6/0)

Update:  You can use a `WHERE` clause at the end of the query to split based on your populated `[99]` field (becomes a field in pivot output, that is:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT Record_ID, Workflow_Step_ID,CAST(DATEDIFF(hour,Start_Date,Complete_Date)*1.0/24 AS DECIMAL(19,1)) AS Day_Diff
              FROM Table1
              )
SELECT *
FROM cte
PIVOT(MAX(Day_DIFF) FOR WorkFlow_Step_ID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[99]))pvt
WHERE [99] IS NULL -- Returns all that weren't terminated, or `IS NOT NULL` for those that are terminated.
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/506b4/12/0)

Comment: Thank you!  This worked for me and I can also use it for other workflows, can't thank you enough.  One follow up question I had was this - I want to create two reports out of this, one that has all the records that have completed the entire workflow, and others that are not.  There is a last step in all workflows (let's call it step 10 for simplicity), and all records that are canceled for whatever reason as they pass through the workflow are sent to step 99.  How/where would you recommend incorporating that into this to do that?  THANK YOU!

Comment: @SDS  You can add a `WHERE` clause at the very end of the above query to get what you're after, see the update.  Also consider clicking the checkmark to indicate this question has been answered.

Comment: Goat CO, Thank you! If I may ask another; I want to run queries in this report to see how long a record has been in the step it is on.  With the WHERE clause I know I can filter out records that have not completed the work flow, but how would I use the 'getdate()' function and some kind of labeling to get that information?
For example, the end results to look like this:
Record     Step 1 Step 2 Step 3  Step 4
Record 1   1.8    2.5     *2.1*  N/A

Where the *2.1* denotes that this record has been in this step for 2.1 days, and the N/A means it has not been in this step yet.  Thank you!

Comment: Goat CO >> Checkmark checked!  Tried to vote it up before but it wouldn't let me, didn't see the checkmark before.

Comment: @SDS So if there was no `Complete_Date` for a step?  That's probably worth posting a new question for, certainly achievable using the `DATEDIFF()` function, like `DATEDIFF(hour,Start_Date,GETDATE())/24.0`

Comment: >> Just realized this is giving me only the single highest value of all the steps, not the value for all the steps in the process.  I took off "Max()" and the query fails.  Any tips?  Also searching to add a totals column for the grand total of how long the record took to go through all the steps if that's easy. Thank you!

Comment: ;WITH cte AS 
(
SELECT 
  CC.Name AS 'Customer Name',
  SPOT.PO_Type AS 'PO Type',
  CWD.Description AS 'Description', 
 -- CWDS.Step_Key,
  CWS.Description AS 'Workflow_Step',
  CWS.Step_Key,
  CAST(DATEDIFF(hour,CWDS.Start_Date,CWDS.Complete_Date)*1.0/24 AS DECIMAL(19,1)) AS "Day_Diff",
  CAST((DATEDIFF(hour,CWDS.Start_Date,CWDS.Complete_Date))*1.0/24 AS DECIMAL(19,1)) AS Max_Day_Diff
<From clause>
SELECT *
FROM cte
PIVOT(Max(Day_Diff) FOR "Workflow_Step" 
      IN (
          [Enter Order],
          [Customer Status Update],
          [Credit Hold Check],
          <etc>
          ))pvt

;

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the last comments, is that regarding the answer with demo above, or part of the expanded stuff you're trying to add?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  This is in regards to the original question.  I tried to post the code to show exactly what I am doing/applying what you were kind enough to post for me.  In my PIVOT results I'm only getting a value for the step that has MAX datediff, all the other results in my PIVOT are showing up as NULL, even though there should be values in it.  My best guess is that since I have two ".description' columns and had to sub in 'FOR "Workflow_Step"'  instead of 'FOR WorkFlow_Step_ID' to get the exact results I needed that it is causing problems. Sorry for so many Qs~!

Comment: @SDS Could you add to the sample data in your question to illustrate the problem?  It might be better to just post a new question with the expanded layout/criteria, it will get more attention.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a pivot table, something along these lines

```
SELECT Record_id, [1] Step1, [2] Step2, [3] Step3, [4] Step4
FROM (
SELECT Record_id, Workflow_Step_id, cast((Datediff(s, Start_Date, Complete_Date) / 86400.0) as decimal(5, 1)) as DayCnt
FROM tablename t) up
PIVOT (Max(DayCnt) FOR Workflow_Step_id IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])) AS pvt
```

Comment: agileMike, Thank you for your response!  I tried this and it worked for exactly what I asked.  At the end of the day I used the other answer because it was easier for me to apply some filters via a Where clause in the select statement and label the columns easier (with the SQL that I know, I'm sure it's very easy for you to do it in this query.)  Thank you for your answer, it did help and I learned a lot by being able to compare both answers.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad it was helpful; I must confess I like the other answer better myself. I wouldn't have posted this one if I had seen the answer Goat CO posted. I've been using SQL Server as my main storage mechanism for 10 years and am just now starting to utilize CTEs. Don't know how I missed them for so long!